# How does the Python interpreter exit after finishing executing code?

Tags: python

Generally, How does the Python interpreter exits?

For example:

```
print('aaa')
```

After executing this code, aside from calling exit handlers registered with `atexit` what else does the interpreter do to free its resources upon normal exit (with no exceptions raised) and without calling `os._exit`?

Is there a main hook/function that the Python interpreter calls on every exit?

```
print('aaa')
_exit()  # called automatically on every exit
```

Comment: I don't actually know the answer, but I'd assume it changes based on which operating system you're using

Comment: It calls into C API to release loaded modules and return status code. What is your intention?

Comment: I have provided an answer, but as @yuvi mentioned, it's difficult to know what exactly you want.

Comment: I'm trying to figure out the mechanics behind the scene.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming that `os._exit()` is not called, all python initializations start the interpreter with `Py_Initialize`, then execute the given Python code, and then pass up the status code to the operating system. It's really this:

```
    n = PyImport_ImportFrozenModule("__main__");
    if (n == 0)
        Py_FatalError("__main__ not frozen");
    if (n < 0) {
        PyErr_Print();
        sts = 1;
    }
    else
        sts = 0;

    if (inspect && isatty((int)fileno(stdin)))
        sts = PyRun_AnyFile(stdin, "<stdin>") != 0;

#ifdef MS_WINDOWS
    PyWinFreeze_ExeTerm();
#endif
    if (Py_FinalizeEx() < 0) {
        sts = 120;
    }

error:
    PyMem_RawFree(argv_copy);
    if (argv_copy2) {
        for (i = 0; i < argc; i++)
            PyMem_RawFree(argv_copy2[i]);
        PyMem_RawFree(argv_copy2);
    }
    PyMem_RawFree(oldloc);
    return sts;
```

Even `sys.exit` simply raises an exception so that the interpreter exits cleanly.

> Is there a main hook/function that the Python interpreter calls on
>   every exit?

Just wrap your `main()` with a try..finally.

Comment: You seem to be looking at the code specifically for frozen scripts.

Comment: Py_Main is too complicated to post in a stack overflow answer. This code is similar enough, yet simple to understand.